# How do I get a background color to fill the entire page and fade into a picture with an svg on top?

Tags: html, css, django, svg

[image: homepage with two backgrounds]

I created a grey color background so I could overlay it on top of a picture I currently have. The picture is in a urls.py file and is passed as the background.  I want the grey to fade into a picture but the grey background isn't covering up the entire screen just some of it. I know it has to do with the padding and margins probably but I am pretty new to html and css. I also have an animation I made with an svg I want to be on top of the grey background. It is doing the fading part but after 10 seconds the grey color comes back and doesn't disappear. I am also using my django server as my backend to run the website.

I have tried making the margins and padding 0 which didn't work and also varying the numbers on the margins and padding which doesn't make it fill the whole website. Here's my code.pen so it's easier to see https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zgzxRz

html code

```
<html>
<div id="header">
  <div id="content">
    <head>
      <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Arimo';
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .animated {
           background-color:grey;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
           -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;animation-duration: 10s;
           padding: 0 0;
           margin:10px;
         }
         @-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
            0% {opacity: 1;}
            100% {opacity: 0;}
         }

         @keyframes fadeOut {
            0% {opacity: 1;}
            100% {opacity: 0;}
         }

         .fadeOut {
            -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
            animation-name: fadeOut;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
    <div id = "animated-example" class = "animated fadeOut"></div>          
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 500 100">  
  <text class="txt1" dy="50">ACCENT
      <animate dur="8s"repeatCount="1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="400; 0" />
  </text> 
</svg> 
</div>
</div>
</html>

<div class="container">
  <form #ppForm= "ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <select class="form-control" #pp (change)="onSelectPP($event.target.value); sfr.value=''">
          <option class="form-control" [value]='' selected>Select protection profile</option>
          <option class="form-control" *ngFor="let i of ppList; let idx = index" [value]=idx id=i>{{ i }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <select class="form-control" #sfr (change)="onSelectSFR($event.target.value); tc.value=''">
          <option class="form-control" [value]='' selected>Select SFR</option>
          <option class="form-control" *ngFor="let j of SFRList; let x = index" [value]=x id=j>{{ j }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <select class="form-control" #tc (change)="onSelectTestCase($event.target.value)">
          <option class="form-control" [value]='' selected>Select test case</option>
          <option class="form-control" *ngFor="let k of testCaseList; let y = index" [value]=y id=k>{{ k }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <input #field *ngFor="let m of fieldList, let z = index" class="form-control inputfield" type="text" placeholder='{{ m }}' (input)="inputToPass[z+4]=$event.target.value; fieldValue[z]=$event.target.value" [value]="fieldValue[z]">
      <div class="buttons">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-e7e7e7" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" class= "btn btn-e7e7e7" (click)="pp.value='';onReset()">Reset</button>
        <button type="globalconfig" class= "btn btn-e7e7e7" (click)="setGlobs()">Set globs</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

css code

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo');
  #header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  }

  #headerContent {
  margin: 0px, auto;  /*need to change length and go to another big page, so scrollign feature/overflow addition?*/
  width: 100%;  /*need to change length and go to another big page, so scrolling feature/overflow addition?*/
  }

  svg {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
   /* background-color:#5c5c5c;*/
  }
  path {
    stroke-dasharray: 100;
    animation: draw 5s forwards; /*had background color but don't need it?? */
  }

  .txt1 {
    font-size:60px;
    fill:none;
    stroke:#fffbfb;
    stroke-dashoffset:400;
    stroke-dasharray:400;
    stroke-width: 4px;
    }    
form{
    max-width: 30em;
    margin-top: 4.5%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color:#93C1B3; /*color for box*/
    padding: 1em 2em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

form h1{
  font-family: "Arimo";
  color:rgb(7, 7, 7);  /* color for word ACCENT*/
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #f8f8f8; /* will want to change the shadow color later maybe once have right font color */
}

form input[type=text]::placeholder{
   font-family: "Arimo";
   color: #666;  /* font for when you type in boxes etc */
}

form .dropdown{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1.5px; 
}

form .inputfield{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1.5px;
  text-align: center;
}
form .buttons{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1px 3px;
}

form .btn{
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #EEF5DB;
  color: #333745;
}

select{
  text-align-last: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-indent: 10px;
}
```

and here is where the picture is being loaded in the backend folder

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>accent</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body style="background-image: url('static/background2.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 100%">
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
<script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule></script><script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule></script><script src="styles-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="styles-es5.js" nomodule></script><script src="vendor-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="vendor-es5.js" nomodule></script><script src="main-es5.js" nomodule></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to stop the animation from resetting

Comment: Would I replace that in path for animation: draw 5s forward? @AhsN

Comment: Add it to the `.animated` css class